# vc++ 64bit program crashes on a new operator when consume several GBs of memory

Tags: visual-c++, crash, 64-bit, new-operator

I have written a 64bit program which consumes a large bunk of memory. When it consumes several GB of memory, it causes an error on a new operator. But in fact there is still several GB of free memory on this machine to spend. And other program runs correctly with much more memory than this one. And I have enabled compilation option /Zm2000 and link option /LARGEADDRESSAWARE. 
What is the cause then?

Comment: The only way to get the new operator to cause a "crash" or "error" is to corrupt the heap with your code.  A very common failure mode in a C++ program.  There's otherwise little point in making us guess exactly what you see.

Comment: Try run Viva64 for you code.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you still have several GB free, you have to remember that memory can become *fragmented*. If there is no *contiguous* block available to satisfy your request, then the allocation will fail with an exception.

Comment: I find it pretty hard to believe that a 16 exabyte (2^64) virtual address space could become so fragmented that you couldn't find a few gigabytes range of virtual addresses.

Comment: @librik Yes, but not _all_ of that range is available. You're still limited by the amount of physical RAM and swap space.